# pgagent - not running jobs - pgpass file is correct - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pgagent

I have Pgagent installed on my Debian OS. Along with Postgresql 9.4.

I have checked .pgpass file as this seems to be the most common cause for a job to not run.

host port 5432 database = * username = postgres password = xxxx.

for both local and the remote host. The database I'm trying to set a job for is on a remote host.

I made sure it was enabled. It's just a simple INSERT script that should repeat every 5 minutes.

No errors are being triggered that I can find. Any ideas of what would cause the job not to run at all - even when selecting 'run now'?

Answer (score 0):

Check postgre db, pgAgent Catalog, pga_jobsteplog

[image]

Comment: The job is loaded in the pga_job table, the jogstep table, and the schedule is there - but nothing in the jobsteplog

Comment: neither joblog? I just use pgAdmin so I can check the jobs messages.

Answer (score 0):

IDK about Linux but I had similar problem in windows where the thing won't run and it doesn't raise any notice on the error even after doing RUN NOW. The only error i could find out was that if i click on the job and click on statistics, i could see like shit ton of times it ran and everytime it  ran, its status was F.
The reason for this failure is becuase the pgagent couldn't connect to the main database of postgresql.
The services of pgagent isn't running at all (as we can see this information under services in task manager in windows).
Forcing the service to run would create a failure which can be viewed in the event manager in windows.
To solve this issue, first try putting that pgpass.txt file in the environment variable (if not automatically put), if this didn't work, then what I did was to uninstall and delete all possible folders of Postgres, pgagent, and pgadmin, clearing out all temp files, clearing out registry details which have been put by Postgres, pgagent, and pgadmin and also from environment variable. Then reinstall it and it would normally work :)